# How to interpret these integrations with DiracDelta?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let us consider the double integral of `DiracDelta[y-x^2]` over the triangle
with vertices at $(-1,0),\,(-1,2),\,(1,0)$.
Mathematica calculates it as an iterated integral

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
(*1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])*)
```

Let us trace that step by step.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {y, 0, 1 - x}] // InputForm
(*ConditionalExpression[DiscreteDelta[-1 + x] -  HeavisideTheta[1/2 - Sqrt[5]/2 + x] + 
HeavisideTheta[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2 + x],Element[x, Reals]]*)
Integrate[%,{x,-1,1}]
(*1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])*)
```

Now let us integrate in  reverse order.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {y, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1 - y}]
(*1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])*)
```

We see a different result from the previous one. Let us trace it.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {x, -1, 1 - y}] // InputForm
(*ConditionalExpression[Boole[-1 < -Sqrt[y] < 1 - y || 1 - y <  -Sqrt[y] < -1]/
(2*Sqrt[Abs[y]]),  Sqrt[y] < 1 || 1 + Sqrt[y] <  y]*)
Integrate[%,{y,0,2}]
(*Undefined*)
```

It's unclear whether the double integral exists in this case and how that double integral is defined.
I have never seen definite multiple integrals of distributions over bounded regions in math literature.
Constructive answers are welcome.

Comment: Additionally, `InverseFourierTransform[
 FourierTransform[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {x, y}, {t, s}], {t, s}, {x, 
  y}]` produces `1/(\[Pi] (x^2 - y)) + DiracDelta[x^2 - y]`.

Answer (score 2):

The integral exists and the first result is ok.

Obviously Mathematica can't transform the nonlinear argument `y-x^2` in your second approach `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {y, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1 - y}]`. The transformation by hand uses the identity `DiracDelta[g[z]]=Sum[(z-zi)/Abs[g'[zi]]], g[zi]==0`.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x + Sqrt[y] ]/( 2 Sqrt[y]) + DiracDelta[x - Sqrt[y] ]/(2 Sqrt[y]), {y, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1 - y}]
(*1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])*)
```

Comment: Thank you. You calculate  the second iterated integral in another way. However, your statement "The integral exists" is ungrounded. I repeat "How that double integral is defined?".  I have never seen definite multiple integrals of distributions over bounded regions in math literature.

Comment: Mathematica actually can't handle correctly the case `DiracDelta[g[x,y]]`. In your case the inner integration variable `y` is quadratic. My way is  a well grounded workaround! Look for example for "Green's Function" to see multiple examples of integrals in bounde regions.

Comment: @user64494 You might find this paper interesting. https://eej.aut.ac.ir/article_511_163e09592b261d64a85a3ca7673d9fbe.pdf

Comment: @BillWats: Having looked in the article, I didn't see multiply integrals from distributions over bounded regions there.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Can you give a precise reference as solid people use to do?

Comment: @user64494 look at eq 37

Comment: And continue to eq 39.

Comment: @user64494 The subclause in your comment is  
dispensable . Regardless , one link with multiple references: [Weisstein mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Sorry, I don't see mutiple integrals over bounded sets there.

Comment: @BillWatts:Thisi s a oneidimensional integral.

Comment: The upvoters, it recalls me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awards_and_decorations_received_by_Leonid_Brezhnev

Comment: @user64494 The link shows definition of `DiracDelatfunction` and hopefully clarifies my answer.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: No, Please, reply seriously. Regard.

Comment: @user64494 from eq33 to eq39, my reference integrates over three variables in succession, which is what you do with a triple integral, even when you don't write it as a triple integral.  In this case the integration is over both sides of an equation, the right hand side consisting of a 3-D DiracDelta in $\rho$, $\phi$, and $z$.  All integration limits are finite.  This, of course, is not the made-up multiple integral you are wanting to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Let us follow the primitive approach to the one-dimensional $\delta$-distribution and let us
approximate `DiracDelta` under the consideration by a bell-shaped function
and let us consider a usual two-dimensional integral.
This can be done in many ways (compare [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and
[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function)).
We start with a rational approximation `f[u_}:=e/Pi/(e^2+u^2)` in hopes to obtain a
closed-form expression for the integral under consideration.
Later we consider the case `g[u_]:=Exp[-u^2/e^2]/Sqrt[Pi]/e` too.
Let's begin.

```
ClearAll[e]; a =  e/Pi*Integrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1]
(*1/(2 \[Pi]) e (1/e 4 (ArcCot[e] + (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[
     e] (-ArcTan[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[e]] + 
       ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[e]])) + 
RootSum[1 + e^2 + 2 #1 - #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (
  Log[1 - #1] #1)/(-1 - #1 + #1^2) &] - 
RootSum[1 + e^2 + 2 #1 - #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (
  Log[-#1] #1)/(-1 - #1 + #1^2) &] + 
RootSum[1 + e^2 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (
  Log[1 - #1] #1)/(-1 + #1 + #1^2) &] - 
RootSum[1 + e^2 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (
  Log[-#1] #1)/(-1 + #1 + #1^2) &])*)
N[a /. e -> 0.001, 20]
(*1.57354 + 0. I*)
```

I'd like to note `N[1/2 + Sqrt[5]/2, 20]` outputs `1.6180339887498948482`.
The above result is confirmed numerically by

```
e = 10^-3; d = e/Pi*NIntegrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
(*1.57353*)
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small

(A warning is not an error communication.) and, making use of the MonteCarlo method,

```
b = e/Pi*NIntegrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^7},AccuracyGoal -> 3,PrecisionGoal -> 2]
(*1.58846*)
```

We consider an integral of a continuous function over a tiangle which exists without shade of doubt and calculate it as an iterated integral. The consideration of the iterated integral in reverse order is not necessary, however, we treat that too. We split the iterated integral into three ones.

```
ClearAll[e]; e/Pi*Integrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {y, 1, 2}, {x, -1, 1 - y}, 
Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1]
(*-((\[Pi] + I \[Sqrt](-1 - I e) \[Pi] - I \[Sqrt](-1 + I e) \[Pi] - 
 2 I \[Sqrt](-1 - I e) ArcTan[\[Sqrt](-1 - I e)] + 
 2 I \[Sqrt](-1 + I e) ArcTan[\[Sqrt](-1 + I e)] - (1 + 
    I) \[Sqrt](-10 I + 
     8 e) ArcTan[(1 + I)/(\[Sqrt](-10 I + 8 e))] + (1 + 
    I) \[Sqrt](10 I + 
     8 e) ArcTanh[(1 + I)/(\[Sqrt](10 I + 8 e))] - 
 I Log[-1 - I e] + I Log[-1 + I e])/(2 \[Pi]))*)
e/Pi*Integrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {y, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 0}, 
Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1]
(*1/(2 \[Pi]) (\[Pi]+2 (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[e] (ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[e]]+
I ArcTanh[(-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[e]])-2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[-I+e] ArcTanh[(-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[-I+e]]-
2 (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[I+e] ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[I+e]]+I (Log[I-e]-Log[I+e]))*)
```

Mathematica fails with the third piece

```
e/Pi*Integrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1 - y}, 
Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1]
(*(e Integrate[((-1)^(
   1/4) (\[Sqrt](e + 
         I y) ArcTanh[((-1)^(3/4) (-1 + y))/(\[Sqrt](e - I y))] + 
     I \[Sqrt](e - 
         I y) ArcTanh[((-1)^(
          1/4) (-1 + y))/(\[Sqrt](e + I y))]))/(2 e \[Sqrt](e^2 + 
      y^2)), {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1])/\[Pi]*)
```

It should be noticed, that the latest integral can be done numerically for concrete values of `e`. Let us continue.

```
-((\[Pi] + I \[Sqrt](-1 - I e) \[Pi] - I \[Sqrt](-1 + I e) \[Pi] - 
   2 I \[Sqrt](-1 - I e) ArcTan[\[Sqrt](-1 - I e)] + 
   2 I \[Sqrt](-1 + I e) ArcTan[\[Sqrt](-1 + I e)] - (1 + 
      I) \[Sqrt](-10 I + 
       8 e) ArcTan[(1 + I)/(\[Sqrt](-10 I + 8 e))] + (1 + 
      I) \[Sqrt](10 I + 
       8 e) ArcTanh[(1 + I)/(\[Sqrt](10 I + 8 e))] - 
   I Log[-1 - I e] + I Log[-1 + I e])/(2 \[Pi])) + 
  1/(2 \[Pi]) (\[Pi] + 
 2 (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[
  e] (ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[e]] + 
    I ArcTanh[(-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[e]]) - 
 2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[-I + e] ArcTanh[(-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[-I + e]] - 
 2 (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[I + e] ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[I + e]] + 
 I (Log[I - e] - Log[I + e])) /. e -> 0.001
(*0.977684 - 1.78111*10^-14 I*)
```

and

```
e = 0.001;(e *NIntegrate[((-1)^(
   1/4) (\[Sqrt](e + 
         I y) ArcTanh[((-1)^(3/4) (-1 + y))/(\[Sqrt](e - I y))] + 
     I \[Sqrt](e - 
         I y) ArcTanh[((-1)^(
          1/4) (-1 + y))/(\[Sqrt](e + I y))]))/(2 e \[Sqrt](e^2 + 
      y^2)), {y, 0, 1}])/\[Pi]
(*0.595856 - 1.37879*10^-17 I*)
```

This is in accordance with the results of completely numeric integration:

```
e=0.001;e/Pi*NIntegrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {y, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1 - y}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
(*1.57354*)
```

and

```
e = 10^-3; c = e/Pi*NIntegrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {y, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1 - y}, 
Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^7}, AccuracyGoal -> 3,PrecisionGoal -> 2]
(*1.56421*)
```

Now we turn to the case of `g[u_]:=Exp[-u^2/e^2]/Sqrt[Pi]/e`. Both iterated symbolic integrations fail, but both numeric integrations produce a different result from the previous ones.

```
e=0.001;e^-1/Sqrt[Pi]*NIntegrate[Exp[-(y - x^2)^2/e^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
(*0.10912*)
```

and

```
e=0.001;e^-1/Sqrt[Pi]*NIntegrate[Exp[-(y-x^2)^2/e^2],{y,0,2},{x,-1,1-y}]
(*0.111262*)
```

The executed codes as nb file on demand through Dropbox.

Addition. In this case one of the iterated integrals is reduced to an one-dimensional integral

```
ClearAll[e];e^-1/Sqrt[Pi]*Integrate[Exp[-(y - x^2)^2/e^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1]
(*(1/(e Sqrt[\[Pi]]))Integrate[1/2 e Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Erf[x^2/e] - Erf[(-1 + x + x^2)/e]),
{x, -1, 1},Assumptions -> e > 0 && e < 1]*)
```

Now calculate the latest integral numerically

```
e := 0.01;NIntegrate[1/2*e *Sqrt[\[Pi]]*(Erf[x^2/e]-Erf[(-1 + x + x^2)/e]), {x, -1, 1}]
   (*0.0274534*)

e:=0.00100000000000000000000000000000000;
NIntegrate[1/2*e *Sqrt[\[Pi]] *(Erf[x^2/e] - Erf[(-1 + x + x^2)/e]), {x, -1, 1},
AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(*0.00282913941636254483746320250663*)
```

Comment: `N[1/(2 \[Pi]) e (1/
       e 4 (ArcCot[
         e] + (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[
          e] (-ArcTan[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[e]] + 
           ArcTanh[(-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[e]])) + 
     RootSum[1 + e^2 + 2 #1 - #1^2 - 
        2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (Log[1 - #1] #1)/(-1 - #1 + #1^2) &] - 
     RootSum[1 + e^2 + 2 #1 - #1^2 - 
        2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (Log[-#1] #1)/(-1 - #1 + #1^2) &] + 
     RootSum[1 + e^2 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 
        2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (Log[1 - #1] #1)/(-1 + #1 + #1^2) &] - 
     RootSum[1 + e^2 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 
        2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (Log[-#1] #1)/(-1 + #1 + #1^2) &]) /. 
  e -> 10^-5, 20]`

Comment: produces `1.6135641088989329018 + 0.*10^-20 I`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your first numerical integral

```
e = 10^-3; d = e/Pi*NIntegrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
(*1.57354*)
```

Change things up a little. Use `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` and make `e` smaller.

```
e = 10^-4; d = e/Pi*Integrate[1/(e^2 + (y - x^2)^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}] // N
(*1.60391 + 0. I*)
```

For `e = 10^-5` we get `d = 1.61356 +0. I` and

for `e = 10^-6` we get `d = 1.6166 +0. I` and

for `e = 10^-10` we get `1.61801984663683206818852997777 + 0.*10^-30 I` when I use `N[#,30]&` instead of `N`.

Clearly we are converging to Mathematica's exact answer.

Comment: Have you looked my comment to my answer? How about `g[u_]:=Exp[-u^2/e^2]/Sqrt[Pi]/e`?